# Ошибка при выполнение чтения

Tags: c#, sqlite3

Пытаюсь прочитать таблицу из Mozilla - Firefox! но мне выдает ошибку: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добавить sqlite3_x64 ? 
Вообще хотелось бы поподробнее узнать)

Comment: что за sqlite_open? Если просто с nuget поставить sqlite то там будет реализация ADO.NET

Comment: @vitidev, Так ну а по факту: Не удалось загрузить DLL, как её загрузить? голова вообще не работает )

Comment: По факту при установке sqlite из nuget он ставит либы System.Data.SQLite.dll и x64/SQLite.Interop.dll, что  работает и ничего про sqlite3_x64 не говорит. Вы же, похоже, пытаетесь использовать чистую сишную dll для sqlite. Я не знаю специфики, но стоит тег c# и может лучше просто использовать ADO.NET Sqlite

Comment: Ну в вашем случае может быть можно пойти и качнуть бинарные реализации например с sqlite.org  и вкинуть их рядом с ехешником и имя длл дать нужное. Ну это если я правильно понимаю, что вы пытаетесь использовать sqlite либу чистую без оберток.